# Динамически сгенерированные кнопки в скролле

Tags: javascript, html, css, прокрутка

У меня есть функция для генерации кнопок.

```
         <script type="text/javascript">
            function createButtonsInScroll(quantityBtns, whereToInsertNode) {
              for (let i = 0; i <= quantityBtns; i++) {
                const buttonNode = document.createElement('button');
                buttonNode.id = `selectbutton${i}`;
                buttonNode.textContent = i;
                whereToInsertNode.append(buttonNode);
                const brNode = document.createElement('br');
                whereToInsertNode.append(brNode);
              }
            }
        </script>
```

В самом коде:

```
<div align="left" class="selectbutton">
        <script type="text/javascript">
            createButtonsInScroll(30, document.body);
        </script>
    </div>
```

У div есть свои параметры css:

```
.selectbutton{
    scrollbar-width: none;
    overflow: auto; 
}
```

Мне надо, чтобы кнопки были в данном div, а не следовали за ним.

Comment: Так передайте соответствующий селектор в createButtonsInScroll функцию, вместо document.body

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Метод `append` вставляет элемент в конец указанной ноды (в вашем случае в конец body).
Вам необходимо передать ту ноду, куда хотите вставить элемент. `createButtonsInScroll(30, document.querySelector('.selectbutton')`
Можете почитать более подробно про методы вставки в этой статье:
https://learn.javascript.ru/modifying-document